# How to initialize a variable to accept any given class

Tags: java, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

I'm designing a jax-rs application. I need to have a common response object to every api call. This is the model of it. UserObject variable should be modified to accept any class that I set using get/set'ers. Currently it can only accept Customer class only. I need this variable to be able to accept Customer,Address,Employee ..... (any thing I pass). How can I do it?

```
public class CustomResponse {
    private Customer UserObject;
    private String Attributes;
    private String Tags;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well, you either have to create an interface or abstract base class, and derive from those.

Comment: Tried It but needs another way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic class for that:

```
public class CustomResponse<T> {
    private T userObject;
    private String Attributes;
    private String Tags;

    //a setter...
    public void setUserObject(T object) {this.userObject = object;}
    public T getUserObject() {return this.userObject;}
}
```

And specific object types can be constructed as:

```
CustomResponse<Customer> customerResponse = new CustomResponse<Customer>();
customerResponse.setUserObject(new Customer());
...
```

In a different resource method:

```
CustomResponse<Address> customerResponse = new CustomResponse<Address>();
customerResponse.setUserObject(new Address());
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement interfaces on your desired objects and, instead Customer class, use this particular interface on your responses:

```
public class CustomResponse {
    private ResponseObject responseObject;
    private String Attributes;
    private String Tags;
    ...
}
```

Then in your interface you can have signature for methods you must have in all classes which implements this:

```
public interface ResponseObject {
    ...
}
```

And then you Customer is, also, a ResponseObject

```
public class Customer implements ResponseObject {
    ...
}
```